# Internet Explorer 11 REST services error 400

Tags: rest

I have generic DELETE request.

```
DELETE /rest/:id
```

when send request I get error 400. I have no problems with another browsers.

```
@At("/rest/:id")
@Delete
public Reply delete(@Named("id") String id) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CityService.class.getName());
}
```

I am using sitebricks(Java).

EDIT: I have replaced DELETE with GET request and worked. Probably DELETE is the problem.

Comment: could you add some more of your code (request code)

Comment: is it an ajax call ?

Comment: yes, i am using ajax.

Comment: *I have replaced DELETE with GET request and worked* that's hardly a solution